# Angular 7 HttpClient post can not parse large request body?

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

Does angular HttpClient have limit on request body size?

I was doing an angular project that consumes a rest API. The API is simple, it's just replace a JSON file whenever the API endpoint to the file hits using POST method, with new JSON object as the request body.

The code runs well if the new JSON object is small and only have some nodes, However the code returns an error with status code 400 and error message "Error when parsing request" when i'm trying to send big object. Does the error caused by the big object or am i doing it incorrectly?

Last time it returns error is when i tried to send big JSON file with ~1.5MB size, the JSON object seems to be valid as several online json formatters report it as a valid json object.

I'm sorry if i didn't explain my problem well, as i'm not native english user, and i'm also quite new in angular world. Thanks

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { take, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { throwError, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});

@Injectable()
export class configService {
    private _url = 'http://some-api-endpoint/';

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    private _save(data):Promise<any> {
        return this.http.post(this._url, data, { headers, responseType: 'text', observe:'response' })        
            .pipe(
                take(1),
                catchError(err => this._handleError(err))
            )
            .toPromise();
    }

    public async updateConfigFile(data): Promise<any> {

        try {
            const json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
            const update = await this._save(json);
            if(update.status === 201) {
                return {
                    success: true,
                    data: update
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    success: false,
                    error: update
                }
            }
        } catch(err) {
            return {
                success: false,
                error: err.message
            }
        }        
    }

    private _handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never>{
        let errObj = {};
        if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
             const err = error.error
             console.warn('An client-side error occured:', {err});
             errObj = {
                 status: 'internal error',
                message: error.error.message
             }   
        } else {
             console.warn(`Backend returned code ${error.status} `, {error});
            errObj = {
                 status: error.status,
                 message: error.error
            }
        }

        return throwError(errObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert it into base64 encoded value and pass it.

Comment: Your post looks valid. The problem might occur on the server-side. For example, PHP has a default post limit 2MB and you can increase it in preferences. What do you use at the backend?

Comment: Also, sometimes it makes sense to perform a request with Postman in order to address uncertainty.

Comment: @Riki Syahputra, what was the solution you came up with? I am stuck similar situation. I am using Angular 6/ASP.NET and using Post request. code works I try to save say 100 rows of grid or so, but fails if more data is passed. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Angular has no issue parsing and sending the message. Though most servers have a limit of how big of a message they will be allowed to receive.

So you need to look at your application configuration and host. The default IIS configuration does not process requests over 30MB to avoid Denial-of-Service attacks. Most frameworks have a maximum much lower than this.

Your options are:

- removing properties from your objects you are serializing or changing property names to take less characters.
- You can update the application/server to handle larger messages.
- you can use a different serializer that sends smaller messages.

TLDR: You have to reduce the character length of your message, or update the limits on your application to accept a huge message.